# Is this considered an acceptable ghusl?

Tags: wudu, ghusl

I had the intention of making ghusl by going under the shower, washing my hair first with shampoo then washing it off. Then washing the top part (front and back) of my body with soap and water, and then washing my private parts with soap and water, then washing the bottom part (front and back) of my body with soap and water. I then rinse my mouth 3 times and my nose 3 times.

Is this considered acceptable ghusl? (I am a woman if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a valid ghusl. There is no difference between a ghusl of man and women. This is a common misconception. There is no textual evidence in Quran and Sunnah to separate a ghusl of a man from women.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaykum,

There are 3 conditions that must be met for ghusl to be valid(with some exceptions). They are:

- The mouth has been gargled
- Water has been put in the nose up till the soft bone
- The whole body has been washed so that not a single hair is dry

If these conditions have been met, ghusl is counted but if they weren't, it most likely isn't.

**NOTE: THIS IS ACCORDING TO THE HANAFI SCHOOL OF FIQH**